# Solving Error correction model (ECM) in R

Tags: r, regression

> I have one data set and I want to calculate coefficients of elasticity
>   with Error correction model-ECM with function lm. I do not know where
>   I'm wrong with code below, but I get results which is not
>   correct.Formula for calculation is ΔPt = a + b0ΔWt + b1Pt-1 + b2Wt-1. 
>   Correct results should be:
>
> Intercept= -2.679358 diff(log(W))= 1.045140 log(P)[-1]=-1.279491
>   log(W)[-1]=1.278038
>
> but I have something different like results below
>
> Intercept= 2.4896 diff(log(W))= 1.1798 log(P)[-1]= 1.2499 log(W)[-1]=
>   -1.2063
>
> So can anybody help me, how to solve this problem ?

```
TEST<-data.frame(  T=c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017),     P=c(1.32225,1.4643,1.59008,1.72585,1.72579,1.93372,2.07582,2.41522,2.30599,2.27247,2.32,2.34942,2.18307,2.2474,2.33428,2.4385,NA),      W=c(10.75985,11.81686,12.75945,13.81505,14.61576,15.6497,17.21165,18.95588,18.78965,19.01828,18.92123,18.48667,18.0731,18.38971,18.90066,19.74001,20.71245))

 summary(lm(diff(log(P)) ~  diff(log(W)) + log(P)[-1] + log(W[-1],data=TEST))
```